# Как получить Intent в asyncTask

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask, android-intent

У меня есть 3 класса Основной в котором проходит авторизация и я получаю токен от сервера,класс фрагмент и класс asynctask для фрагмента. Вопрос века, как получить intent в классе asynctask, если он не привязан к фрагменту. Получить intent во фрагменте и потом пробывать его использовать в классе asynctask, то asynctask требует что бы получение intent было статично, но getActivity() не может быть статично. Как вы поступаете в таких случаях?

Comment: Вряд ли такой ответ вам поможет, но в таких случаях мы не используем AsyncTask.

Comment: Но тогда, если использовать обычный Thread, то я не смогу к примеру изменять TextView после того , как поток закончился или я что то путаю?

Comment: Не, вы не так поняли. Thread - это тоже не наш случай. Всё это уже очень устаревшие варианты, хорошими разработчиками не используемые. Если попроще, то обратите внимание на Loader'ы, если хотите быть в тренде - то RxJava. И то, и другое, заточено на асинхронные операции, но в отличие от всего вышеперечисленного вами - удобно в использовании и функционально.

Comment: Все верно, таких случаев не возникает. И при использовании AsyncTask и при использовании Thread, Loader, RxJava, Robospice и проч никому не надо пробрасывать intent через фрагмент. Приводите код (минимальный пример), его точно надо выпрямлять.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Так как был уставший, очень затупил. Нужно было лишь AsyncTask сделать дочерним классом основного класса.